# NSNotification fails in iPhone simulator, not in iPad device and not in iPad simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have an event that is called like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:VIDEO_REQUESTED object:nil userInfo:dictionary];
```

The event method IS called when I run the code on my iPad device or the ipad simulator.

In the iphone simulator however, the method IS NEVER called, it fails silently.

The method called is like this:

```
- (void)videoRequested:(NSNotification *) notification {

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [notification userInfo];
    NSString *stringValueToUse = [dictionary valueForKey:@"imgID"];



    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    } else {

        //
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    }


    [AdColony playVideoAdForZone:@"-" withDelegate:self withV4VCPrePopup:YES andV4VCPostPopup:YES];

}
```

Comment: sorry but how is the post done... add more code to that and:

Comment: show the calls to addObserver you are making to get the notification

Comment: In the view Controller I add: 
    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(videoRequested:)
                                                 name:VIDEO_REQUESTED
                                               object:nil];
     
the postNotification is done in a different viewController that is presented modally, anything else you need of info?

Comment: yes where is that code ;) viewDidLoad or where.. also could you please put it in the Question body to format it